# Remove everything from Array which is not in other Array with one common field

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, like this:

```
a = [
    {"id": "peter", "age": "25"},
    {"id": "dave", "age": "34"},
    {"id": "jack", "age": "28"}];

b = [{"id": "peter", "profession": "engineer"}];
```

Now what I need to do is remove everything from array `a` which is NOT in `b` based on the `"id"`, so "dave" and "jack" both need to go. How can this be accomplished efficiently? The only common field between the arrays is the `id` field.

Comment: Find size. Iterate lesser sized array. compare ids. if matches, remove it.

Comment: Array `b` has invalid syntax. It's an object, but with square brackets?

Comment: Are you sure this is the syntax of your `a` array? I'd expect: `[{"id":"peter","age":"25"},{"id":"dave","age":"34"}]` since your version is invalid syntax as well.

Comment: Was intended for demonstration, should be fine now. I do realize what I have to do "mathematically", my question was how it can be done efficiently (since I have much bigger arrays), especially matching the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` on your array like this,

```js
a = [
    {"id": "peter", "age": "25"},
    {"id": "dave", "age": "34"},
    {"id": "jack", "age": "28"}];

b = [{"id": "peter", "profession": "engineer"}, {"id": "dave", "profession": "engineer"}];

filter = b.map(function(person) {
  return person.id;
})

filteredArray = a.filter(function(person) {
  return filter.indexOf(person.id) > -1;
})

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: fails if b has more than one element

Comment: I have updated my answer for multiple values in array b

Answer (score 0):

If `b` isn't too large, build a dictionary to speed up lookups:

```
var bDict = {};
b.forEach(function (person) {
  bDict[person.id] = 1;
});
```

Then use `filter` to remove the entries:

```
filtered = a.filter(function (person) {
  return bDict[person.id];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a backwards loop. It's backwards because when `splice()` removes elements, some objects might be skipped. For example, there are 3 people with indices `0`, `1` and `2`. If index `1` is spliced, the array's length is now 2 and the loop exists without checking for the third person.

```js
var a = [
    {"id": "peter", "age": "25"},
    {"id": "dave", "age": "34"},
    {"id": "jack", "age": "28"}];

var b = [{"id": "peter", "profession": "engineer"}];

function removeExtra() {
  for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var contained = false;

    b.forEach(function(be) {
      if (be.id === a[i].id) {
        contained = true;
      }
    });

    if (!contained) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

removeExtra();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: why do you use a `for` loop if you know of `forEach`?

Comment: Because I need it to go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var duplicateId=[];

 b.forEach(function(e){
     duplicateId.push(e.id);
   });
 a.filter(function (e){
    return (duplicateId.indexOf(e.id)===-1)
  });
 console.log(a);
```